# how to run jQuery code only in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, browser-detection

I am tasked to put jQuery into a webapp, needful of functionality specific to the Internet Explorer 8 browser (7 is not needed). How to do this?

In jQuery 1.8 could do:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '8') { /* does not matter */ }
```

In version 1.9 `$.browser` is removed. The recommended `$.support` does not help.

Comment: I dont think I understand the question. Are you trying to add jQuery to IE8? If so, what exactly is it your trying to add?

Comment: You only want to load jQuery for Internet Explorer 8? Is a different version loaded for IE9+?

Comment: mr sampson, goal is FUNCTION execute only when user bowser of IE 8

Comment: Stop doing browser detection. Tell us what you have that doesn't work in IE8 and we can probably help you make it work in IE8 without having to remove functionality.

Answer (score 7):

### Browser detection vs. feature detection

`$.browser` is deprecated from jQuery *for a reason* (since 1.3). Using it for stuff like you wanted to use it for is not a recommended practice. If you are depending on a certain feature, test for that feature (this is called [feature detection](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/12/29/feature-detection-is-not-browser-detection/), `$.support` is one way to do this) instead of testing for a specific browser.

### Conditional Comments

If you really need to target old IE, use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) (can easily be removed when old IEs do not exist anymore and does not bloat other browsers unnecessarily):

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script src="my_ie8_specific_stuff.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Inside `my_ie8_specific_stuff.js` you can write anything you need, it will only be executed on IE8.

### Conditional class on the `<html>` element

Another way of doing it is putting a class on your `<html>` tag with conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html>         <!--<![endif]-->
```

[This clever and tricky technique](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) will put an `ie8` class on `html` in IE8, any other browser will not get it.

You can easily check for this in jQuery:

```
var isIE8 = $('html').hasClass('ie8');
```

Comment: is of not possible, FUNCTION locate inside PLUGIN - no reason for script incluse file multiply

Comment: @PRASHANTP No reason for your script to include IE8 specific stuff, that's what I say. But I added another technique you might find useful.

Answer (score -2):

If by chance you're using Kendo in your app you don't have to add anything. A class is automaticly generated when you're in the different browsers.
If you want to check if it's ie8, you can do it simply like that:

```
if($('html').hasClass('k-ie8'))
    // do something
```

Comment: Some kind of framework, library, etc., either client or server side, adds these classes for you. So your answer is not really useful until you find out what is adding these classes, and even then, it will be too specific to help. In my answer I outlined the technique which should be used to add these classes to `<html>`.